# Assigning Well-Posed Boundary Conditions for the Wave Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

This is not a homework question. I came across this while studying for an exam and I don't know how to answer it. The question is this:

Consider the slightly modified wave equation $$u_{tt} - u_{xx} + u =0, \,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ for } (x,t) \in (0,1) \times (0,\infty)$$ with smooth initial conditions $u(x,0) = \phi(x)$, $u_t(x,0) = \psi(x)$, $x \in (0,1).$ For what choices of real constants $a,b,c,d$ do the boundary conditions \begin{align*}
au_x(0,t) + bu_t(0,t) &= 0,  \\
cu_x(1,t) + du_t(1,t) &= 0, \,\,\,\,\,\,\, t > 0
\end{align*} lead to a well-posed equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation you consider is called the [*Klein-Gordon equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation). To solve the given boundary value problem, you need the associated  [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) (see [here](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/lpde/lpde203.pdf) and [here](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/lpde/lpde204.pdf) for more information). Since you want to answer questions about which boundary conditions are possible, it's probably the most useful to derive the associated Green's function yourself, e.g. along [these lines](http://homepages.physik.uni-muenchen.de/~helling/classical_fields.pdf). Well-posedness of the problem is then equivalent with the existence of a Green's function.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was struggling to find any solid references.